# ListView not responding to Click or KeyPress

Tags: android

I have a simple ListView in my layout.xml file.

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/action_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And in my javacode, I add a setOnItemClickListener() to my listview:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        System.out.println ("get onItem Click position= "+position);
    }
});
```

But when I run on G1. I don't see any print out when I click an item on the ListView on the phone.
Or when I select an item using track ball and press CENTER.

Can you please tell me why to resolve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The click listener is working; the problem is that `System.out.println()` doesn't work on Android.  On Android you use [android.util.Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) for logging data from the phone.  For example, you'd use:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.v("MyApp", "get onItem Click position= " + position);
    }
});
```

Then in Eclipse, you should open up the LogCat view (Window --> show view --> other --> android --> LogCat).  Your log should end up there.  Alternatively, you can use the [ddms tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) to view phone logs.